# Implementing IDisposable Asp.net core api Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dispose, idisposable

I'm creating ASP.NET Core API. I'm have problem which memory. When a lot of connect to my api, memory allocation more 500mb. When i create Dispose method in my Controller, my api use only 200mb memory but using a lot of CPU resourses. In official doc for asp.net core writed what  use Dispose method this is bad practice. you can give me recomendation about this?

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class myPasswdController : ControllerBase, IDisposable
{
    private bool disposed = false;

    [HttpGet]
    async public Task<IActionResult> GetPasswd()
    {
        ImyPasswdService myPasswdService = new myPasswdService();
        return await Task.FromResult(Ok(new Response<ImyPasswd>(myPasswdService.Get(1, 12, new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 }))));
    }

    [HttpGet("{len}")]
    async public Task<IActionResult> GetPasswd(int len)
    {
        ImyPasswdService myPasswdService = new myPasswdService();
        return await Task.FromResult(Ok(new Response<ImyPasswd>(myPasswdService.Get(1, len, new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 }))));
    }

    [HttpGet("{len}:{maks}")]
    async public Task<IActionResult> GetPasswd(int len, string maks)
    {
        int[] bin_mask = new int[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < maks.Length; i++)
            bin_mask[i] = maks[i] - '0';
        ImyPasswdService myPasswdService = new myPasswdService();
        return await Task.FromResult(Ok(new Response<ImyPasswd>(myPasswdService.Get(1, len, bin_mask))));
    }

    [HttpGet("{len}:{maks}/{count}")]
    async public Task<IActionResult> GetPasswd(int len, string maks, int count)
    {
        int[] bin_mask = new int[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < maks.Length; i++)
            bin_mask[i] = maks[i] - '0';
        ImyPasswdService myPasswdService = new myPasswdService();
        return await Task.FromResult(Ok(new Response<ImyPasswd>(myPasswdService.Get(count, len, bin_mask))));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                
                //GC.Collect();
            }
            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    ~myPasswdController()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs i set Singleton pattern:

```
services.AddSingleton<ImyPasswdService, myPasswdService>();
```

Comment: Please, show us some of your code.

Comment: Your IDisposable implementation and finalizer do absolutely nothing. What problem is there with using 500 MB of RAM? And yes, if you uncomment that line and force garbage collection after every Dispose() call, memory usage will go down and CPU usage will go up, solving nothing.

Comment: As for your startup, you bypass dependency injection using `ImyPasswdService myPasswdService = new myPasswdService();`...

Comment: Yes. I'm fixed it

Comment: Hi @runes What is there inside PasswordService? Do you have some unmanaged fields there? like Database connection? If then you have to implement the IDisposable in the PasswordService and dispose the un-managed resources (like database connection)

Answer (score 0):

`IDisposable` is for unmanaged resources. Your controller doesn't and shouldn't use unmanged resources, so there is no point in it implementing `IDisposable`. ASP.NET Core and .NET Core take care of memory for you, and in the case of Controllers, they are instantiated and discarded as needed, so they won't be in memory for long.

> In Startup.cs i set Singleton pattern:

While you correctly inject a singleton service, you aren't using that service anywhere. Instead of using constructor injection to take advantage of the service, you're manually instantiating the dependency.

Your code should look more like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class myPasswdController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ImyPasswdService _passwordService;

    public myPasswdController(ImyPasswdService passwordService)
    {
        _passwordService = passwordService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    async public Task<IActionResult> GetPasswd()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(Ok(new Response<ImyPasswd>(_passwordService.Get(1, 12, new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 }))));
    }

    [HttpGet("{len}")]
    async public Task<IActionResult> GetPasswd(int len)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(Ok(new Response<ImyPasswd>(_passwordService.Get(1, len, new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 }))));
    }

    [HttpGet("{len}:{maks}")]
    async public Task<IActionResult> GetPasswd(int len, string maks)
    {
        int[] bin_mask = new int[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < maks.Length; i++)
            bin_mask[i] = maks[i] - '0';

        return await Task.FromResult(Ok(new Response<ImyPasswd>(_passwordService.Get(1, len, bin_mask))));
    }

    [HttpGet("{len}:{maks}/{count}")]
    async public Task<IActionResult> GetPasswd(int len, string maks, int count)
    {
        int[] bin_mask = new int[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < maks.Length; i++)
            bin_mask[i] = maks[i] - '0';

        return await Task.FromResult(Ok(new Response<ImyPasswd>(_passwordService.Get(count, len, bin_mask))));
    }
}
```

As general comments, you should follow c# naming conventions and get rid of all `await Task.FromResult` that are pointless in the code above.